# How to remove auto play function from a flash videoplayer?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

First of All I'm not good in action scripting.

I have a flash videoplayer that playing automatically when enter the site, it makes the site become slow to load, actually there is button called 'Play Video'. Ican see a code in the action panel in the first frame

```
Stage.showMenu = false;
import mx.video.*;
import flash.external.*;

var videoListenerObject:Object = new Object();
videoListenerObject.stopped = function(eventObject:Object):Void {
    trace(video_FLVPlybk.state + ": playhead time is: " + eventObject.playheadTime);
    gotoAndPlay("finish");
};
```

Although the play video button have a script like this.. and I can also find three labels named 'start', 'video_play' and 'finish'

```
on (release) {
//  flash.external.ExternalInterface.call("pageTracker1._trackEvent", "Videos", "Play", "autoplay_home-tb");
//  flash.external.ExternalInterface.call("pageTracker2._trackEvent", "Videos", "Play", "autoplay_home-tb");
    flash.external.ExternalInterface.call("flashVideoClicked", "autoplay_home-tb");
    gotoAndPlay ("video_play");
}
```

I didn't get an idea how to stop the autoplay function..

Thanks!

Akhil

Comment: Is the video player a Flash component (pre-build by Adobe)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the ActionScript 2.0 FLVPlayback component, you maybe able to set the property `autoPlay` to false

```
video_FLVPlybk.autoPlay = false;
var videoListenerObject:Object = new Object();
//etc...
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00002375.html